# Algorithm - Find pure numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

> Description:
>
> A positive integer m is said to a pure number if and only if m can be
>   expressed as q-th power of a prime p (q >= 1).  Here your job is easy,
>   for a given positive integer k, find the k-th pure number.
>
> Input:
>
> The input consists of multiple test cases. For each test case, it
>   contains a positive integer k (k<5,000,000). Process to end of file.
>
> Output:
>
> For each test case, output the k-th pure number in a single line. If
>   the answer is larger than 5,000,000, just output -1.
>
> Sample input:
>
> 1
>
> 100
>
> 400000
>
> Sample output:
>
> 2
>
> 419
>
> -1

Original page: http://acm.whu.edu.cn/learn/problem/detail?problem_id=1092

Can anyone give me some suggestion on the solution to this?

Comment: You may avoid to use the pow function every loop. I think it will be faster to put `tmp=1` before the inner loop and then `tmp*=p[i];` inside, instead of pow.

Comment: I found my code does not accord with the the request of the problem, so I removed the link to my code.

Comment: @Simone-Cu So `pow()` isn't executing very fast, is it?

Comment: Pow is quite fast ok, but for what you need, you are looking for consecutive power of a number.
The call of a function is slower against an easy multiply operation and you can avoid it in this case.

Comment: `std::pow` on integers can very likely be inlined.  But profile or examine assembly if you need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already figured out all the pure numbers, which is the tricky part. Sort the ones less than 5 million and then look up each input in turn in the resulting array.

To optimize you need to efficiently find all primes up to 5 million (note `q >= 1` in the problem description: every prime is a pure number), for which you will want to use some kind of sieve (sieve of Erathosthenes will do, look it up).

You could probably adapt the sieve to leave in powers of primes, but I expect that it would not take long to sieve normally and then put the powers back in. You only have to compute powers of primes p where p <= the square root of 5 million, which is 2236, so this shouldn't take long compared with finding the primes.

Having found the numbers with a sieve, you no longer need to sort them, just copy the marked values from the sieve to a new array.

Having now looked at your actual code: your QuickSort routine is suspect. It performs badly for already-sorted data and your array will have runs of sorted numbers in it. Try `qsort` instead, or if you're supposed to do everything yourself then you need to read up on pivot choice for quicksort.

Comment: How he can quick find a Prime number? Also power maybe 1 and he need search all primes less than 5000000.

Comment: @Толя: sorry, I don't understand your question. The set of all primes less than 5 million can be found quickly using the sieve of Eratosthenes (or the sieve of Atkin, not sure which would be quicker here but Eratosthenes is easier to code). I don't see any need to find a particular prime quickly.

Comment: Just for reference, a completely naive implementation of the Sieve of Erathosthenes in Python takes 7 seconds on my machine to compute a  list of primes under 5000000. Obviously one can do a lot better with a couple of tricks, and likely C would be much faster anyway. The time limit on the challenge is 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int max = 5000000;
    int[] dp = new int[max];
    for (int i = 2; i < max; i++)
    {
        if (dp[i] == 0)
        {
            long t = i;
            while (t < max)
            {
                dp[t] = 1;
                t *= i;
            }
            int end = max / i;
            for (int j = 2; j < end; j++)
                if (dp[i * j] == 0)
                    dp[i * j] = 2;
        }
    }

    int[] result = new int[348978];
    int pointer = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < max; i++)
    {
        if (dp[i] == 1)
            result[pointer++] = i;
    }
}
```

Into array as **"1"** marked pure numbers.
As **"2"** marked non pure(prime) numbers.

For each output check array ranges if it inside output **result[index]** if not output should be -1.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The result is correct, but somehow exceeds the time limit...

Comment: Change from "(int j = 2; j < end; j++)", to "(int j = i; j < end; j++)" (Because we already check it). Must help.

Comment: This is really weird...Still exceeds...Thanks anyway, I suppose something wrong with the ACM server, as it works very fast on my own machine.

Comment: You also may change from "int[] dp" to "byte[] dp", this decrease memory usage and as consequence a bit decrease time usage.

Comment: So sorry that exceeding time limit is my own mistake.... Your algorithm is correct. Thank you for your aid.